# Angular 4: Disable html template of grandparent

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a component with following routes

```
    {
         path: ':id', component: ProjectDetailsComponent,
         children: [
           {path: '', redirectTo: 'gathering', pathMatch: 'full'},
           {path: 'gathering', component: DeviceComponent},
           {
                path: 'mapping/:migWindowId', component: MigrationWindowComponent,
                children: [
                  {path: '', redirectTo: 'premigration', pathMatch: 'full'},
                  {path: 'premigration', component: PreMigrationComponent,
                       canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
                ]
           }
        ]
     }
```

So, PremigrationComponent is grandchild of ProjectDetailsComponent and MigrationWindowComponent being in the middle.

Template for ProjectDetailsComponent is like this

```
<div class="ui-step ui-step--alt active ui-step-change">
 <div class="step__icon step__icon--small" [routerLink]="['gathering']">1</div>
 <div class="step__label">Data Gathering</div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And template for MigrationWindowComponent is

```
<div class="ui-step ui-step--alt active ui-step-change">
    <div class="step__icon step__icon--small" [routerLink]="['premigration']">1</div>
    <div class="step__label">Pre Migration</div>
</div><router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

What I'm trying is, I want to hide the template above the `<router-outlet>` tag of Grandparent when a template of grandchild is loaded. I tried with with event emitters to achieve this by notifying parent and then its parent. But I feel it's not an elegant way. Is there any optimization for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "disabling" a template? hiding everything in it? (that would include the `router-outlet`)

Comment: @MondKin My mistake. I want to hide only the template above <router-outlet>, not <router-outlet>

Answer (score 0):

## First option:

If you are having that problem maybe the children should be siblings instead:

```
[
    {
         path: ':id', component: ProjectDetailsComponent,
         children: [
           {path: '', redirectTo: 'gathering', pathMatch: 'full'},
           {path: 'gathering', component: DeviceComponent},
        ]
     },
     {
         path: ':id/mapping/:migWindowId', component: MigrationWindowComponent,
         children: [
           {path: '', redirectTo: 'premigration', pathMatch: 'full'},
           {path: 'premigration', component: PreMigrationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
         ]
     }
]
```

## Second option

If you don't want #1, you can remove from the DOM the parents' components based on the current url (look at the [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) class):

```
<div class="ui-step ui-step--alt active ui-step-change"
     *ngIf="noChildrenActivated()">
   <div class="step__icon step__icon--small" [routerLink]="['gathering']">1</div>
   <div class="step__label">Data Gathering</div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And in `ProjectDetailsComponent`:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

public noChildrenActivated()
{
    const currentUrl =  this.router.routerState.snapshot.url;
    const urlMatchesChildren = new RegExp('/.*/mapping/.*/premigration').test(currentUrl);
    return !urlMatchesChildren;
}
```

As the `noChildrenActivated()` function is used in the template, Angular will execute it each time its value could have changed (quite often) including when switching from one page to another.

Comment: Can you please elaborate anyChildrenActivated() method? And will this method returns any true/false value each time routing changed, i.e even by it's child components?

Comment: Updated the answer. Also, is there a reason for not making them siblings?